# Refiguring for AMT, detailed instructions

Tags: united-states, income-tax, alternative-minimum-tax

I really wanted to understand my federal taxes, so I decided to prepare them for 2023 "by hand" using the fillable PDF forms offered by the IRS. No problems -- except for one thing. I'm now trying to refigure various amounts for the AMT (Form 6251). The instructions for 6251 do not offer any guidelines for making these calculations, they simply tell you to refigure. I've scoured the Internet and even used ChatGPT and Gemini, and cannot find any instructions for refiguring anywhere. I'm specifically interested in 6251, lines 2k and 2n.  Can anyone tell me where I can find detailed instructions to refigure as required? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The instructions are actually [pretty detailed](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i6251#en_US_2023_publink64277pd0e870).

**Every year** you must track your taxes based on the "regular" calculation and the "AMT" calculation. For vast majority of the US taxpayers, that would be the same, but for some it isn't. Certain items are taxed differently under the AMT regime, and certain deductions are removed in it. So for example, if you had ISOs that you executed before and was charged AMT on, then the basis of these shares under AMT would be different than under the regular regime (that's the most common example, and is also the example in the instructions). So you need to recalculate the gain/loss from that disposition.

You'll need to track your prior tax returns and find these items, and review your current year and identify if you have any, and then re-figure the amounts accordingly.

Tax preparation software usually does that for you and prepares all the schedules to track the regular and the AMT basis and refigures all the forms. [This TurboTax article](https://turbotax.intuit.com/tax-tips/irs-tax-return/alternative-minimum-tax-common-questions/L50YotKHP) summarizes the line instructions (but basically parrots the IRS instructions).

---

From the comments it seems that you're not entirely sure what AMT is. You'll need to familiarize yourself with the concept of "items of tax preference" and what adjustments to deductions/income you must made under AMT. See the [26 USC Part VI](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/subtitle-A/chapter-1/subchapter-A/part-VI).

Generally, AMT works through recalculating your whole taxable income again under a different set of rules, and certain items that get preferential treatment (like certain ways to depreciate property, or tax-preferred treatment of ISOs) do not get that treatment under the AMT. So for the affected assets you'd need to track their "AMT basis".

For example, if you executed ISOs and kept the shares, the discount you got would be recognized for AMT purposes as income, making your taxable income higher and your tax basis in the shares would be the FMV (and not the strike price as for the regular income tax, which is the "I" part of the ISO)

Also, certain deductions are limited under AMT, so what can count as a deduction that can reduce your income under the regular tax would be less, or unavailable, thus making your taxable income under AMT higher.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  The link you provided is familiar.  But I don't see how the directions are clear at all.  For example:  " . . . then, refigure Form 4684, Form 4797, Form 8949, and Schedule D for the AMT, if applicable, by taking into account any adjustments you made this year or in previous years that affect your basis or otherwise result in a different amount for the AMT."  Okay, but how does one take into account the adjustments, and how are those adjustments made in the first place? Where are the directions on making adjustments?

Comment: @JeffreyJ every year you would have two versions of these forms: one for regular tax calculation and one for AMT. The AMT one *may* have a very different basis for your position than the regular one. So you'll basically fill each of these forms twice, for each set of rules. The instructions for each form refer to AMT, for example Schedule D instructions [here](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040sd#en_US_2022_publink1000285565)

Comment: On a more general note, if you have to deal with AMT, I'm sure you can afford the paid version of the tax preparation software. The US taxes are not made to be calculated manually.

Comment: I calculated my US taxes manually for a few decades using spreadsheets -- basically a homebrew version of the tax prep software -- but switched to commercial products because they were less effort to work with, especially as I started having investments and real estate and the like. I've used three or four different publisher's tools over the years, and sone were easier to use or more informative/helpful than others but they all worked. And the cost of purchasing the tool can be written off on the next year's taxes. The convenience is worth it for me; your milage will vary.

Comment: (The IRS is testing early versions of a free online tax tool. Doesn't yet handle more than the most common cases, isn't universally available, doesn't automate generating the state and/or local returns... but that may eventually be an interesting alternative if Congress allows them the funds to complete it properly )

Comment: @littleadv  Okay.. Thanks. Now we may be making some progress.  So I went and got the instructions for schedule D. I searched the keyword alternative. It only appears once in those instructions. This was the link you sent me. Do I interpret that to mean that this is ONLY way that the AMT version of schedule D differs from the standard version?

Comment: @keshlam.  Yes I've heard about the IRS tool.  I hope it comes about .  That one does not already exist tells me that there are lobbying forces that have blocked it up to this point. So I'm not entirely optimistic.

Comment: @JeffreyJ AMT affects the calculation of basis. May I ask why you're doing these calculations? What asset did you dispose of that falls under AMT rules?

Comment: I don't think I disposed of any asset that falls under those rules.  I simply sold some stocks for a profit through my Fidelity brokerage account. So, on 6251 line 2k, I think I simply enter  0.00.

Comment: Yes, if the asset or the transaction has no special AMT treatment then the diff should be 0.

Answer (score 4):

AMT is certainly one of the more challenging parts of the US tax code (which isn't easy to start with).

The problem with AMT is that it can generate horribly entangled multi-year dependencies and in order to calculate AMT due or AMT credit for 2023 you may have to track items from many years ago (mostly 2019 in my case). If you didn't carry these items carefully through on a year by year bases, you have a large chunk of work (and potentially loss of money) on your hand.

In essence you need to create 2 different federal tax returns for each year one with and one without AMT "trigger" items. For example, your return(s) for 2020 depends on BOTH versions of the 2019 returns, etc.

While this can be done by hand (depending on your specifics) your best shot is to do the tax return of each of the relevant years in the same tax program, have it carried forward by this program and hope for the best.